# IndexError: list index out of range python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

So I have tried to get solutions on this but I haven't really gotten the help I require...I have code to identify a similar list in a list comprised of lists and then it has to identify the string in the identified similar list so that I can use it in an `if` statement. Whenever I try to get that result however, I get an error and I truly cant seem to get over it.

This is the code:

```
listA = [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 423], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 430], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 398], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 507], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 392], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 169], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 149], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 397], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 387], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 448], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 433], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 355], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 477], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 484], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 520], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 500], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 167], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 373], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 328], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 557], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 203], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 519], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 15], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 498], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 481], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 359], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 414], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 510], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 403], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 360], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 494], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 374], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 149], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 131], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 326], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 179], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 530], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 163], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 338], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 427], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 422], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 134], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 443], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 386], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 144], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 356], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 513], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 497], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 424], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 200], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 369], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 149], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 492], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 164], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 413], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 144], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 399], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 16], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 385], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 28], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 406], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 393], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 156], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 157], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 383], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 163], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 347], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 372], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 385], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 143], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 355], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 111], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 367], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 386], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 20], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 494], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 162], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 430], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 152], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 358], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 393], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 357], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 28], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 134], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 179], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 22], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 377], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 146], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 158], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 134], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 407], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 167], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 154], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 190], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 184], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 354], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 316], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 145], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 367], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 170], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 175], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 410], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 304], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 166], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 27], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 153], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 146], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 30], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 29], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 163], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 152], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 30], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 38], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 157], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 30], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 13], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 176], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 24], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 27], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 17], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 35], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 21], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 22], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 20], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', 'down', 1]]

listB = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0']


def fl(list1, list2):
    index = -1
    occ = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(list2):
        if l[:len(list1)] == list1:
            if l[-1] > occ:
                index = i
                occ = l[-1]
    if index == -1:
        return "The 1st list doesn't appear in the 2nd one."
    else:
        print(f"The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index {index} with a number of occurrences equal to {occ}.")
        u = "up"
        y = "down"
        look_up = [(''.join(str(a[:6])), str(a[6])) for a in list2]
        if (''.join(list1), u) in look_up:
            print("up")

        elif (''.join(list1), y) in look_up:
            print("down")

print(fl(listB, listA))
```

This is the output:

```
The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index 0 with a number of occurrences equal to 423.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nkosi\PycharmProjects\study 6.1\study7.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(fl(listB, listA))
  File "C:\Users\nkosi\PycharmProjects\study 6.1\study7.py", line 22, in fl
    look_up = [(''.join(str(a[:6])), str(a[6])) for a in list2]
  File "C:\Users\nkosi\PycharmProjects\study 6.1\study7.py", line 22, in <listcomp>
    look_up = [(''.join(str(a[:6])), str(a[6])) for a in list2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the output I want:

```
The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index 0 with a number of occurrences equal to 423.
up
```

I'm sure I've even asked this question one too many times but I am really getting nowhere...please help

Comment: Last element of `listA` has only 4 elements and you're trying to access 7th which causes an exception.

Comment: even after i remove that one instead now i get  'none' output....still not the outcome I'm looking for

Comment: Because your `fl()` function actually returns something only in once scenario which never happened with this input data.

Answer (score 0):

For avoid `IndexError`, you should add if-else statement in list comprehension.

```py
look_up = [(''.join(str(a[:6])), str(a[6])) if len(a) >= 7 else ('', '') for a in list2]
```

When you change this line, output look likes this.

```bash
The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index 0 with a number of occurrences equal to 423.
```

Furthermore, the contents within `look_up` are incorrect. Your look_up is not successfully generating a string from the list. The following successfully displayed `up`. Please try this.

```py
look_up = [(''.join(a[:6]), str(a[6])) if len(a) >= 7 else ('', '') for a in list2]
```

Comment: it seems to work for the most part, but lets say listB was comprised of index 3 of listA the output would then have to be 'down' however, it still returns 'up'....what could be causing that and how could i solve that

Comment: @damian2345673 That's because the array `[0,0,0,0,1,0,up]` exists elsewhere in `listA`. Conditional expression
`if (''.join(list1), u) in look_up:`
is true, only "up" is output and whether "down" exists is not determined.
If you want to determine both, you should change elif to if. In this case, both "down" and "up" will be output.